# How can I move a window without touching the titlebar in Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, window, aquaris

Somehow I've managed to move the settings window such that its titlebar is not visible. I cannot figure out how to move the window! Basically I'm looking for the equivalent of `Alt` + click for Ubuntu Touch. A reboot still has the window at the same position.

[image]

Comment: Are you using convergence, i.e. your apps are running in Windowed mode witha bluetooth mouse connected?

Comment: I tried it,too. After moving a window on my phone with the mouse beond the system's status bar, it is not possible to click on the bar of the window to move it back. May we could commit a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a workaround which is available cause of a fullScreenBug:
1. Open the gallery-app and open any picture
2. Select once your hidden window so that both windows are visible.
3. Click the picture in the gallery app to switch to full screen view.
Now the system title bar dissapears and you can see and move the bar of your hidden window.

I know it is a little confusing, but it worked for me and it could help until the bug fix is available over OTA.

Comment: Oh, what a clever trick! That was silly, but worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Great! Thanks for feedback. But may be we should report the full screen bug.:D

Answer (score 1):

This bug was fixed in the package unity8 - 8.11+16.04.20151112.1-0ubuntu1. The solution presented was to prevent windows from being moved under the panel.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity8/+bug/1438465